# How much is modest in this case for the usefulness of two-way fixed effects?

Tags: fixed-effects-model, difference-in-difference

Regarding the usefulness of two-way fixed effect (TWFE), Guido Imbens mentioned that TWFE can be good starting point for DiD if the N and T are modest, I am wondering is there any criteria for "modest", how much is modest here?

From this [Chaisemartin, 2020, slide 2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zd3sh9yu9258m0p/Two_Way_Fixed_Effects_With_Heterogeneous_Treatment_Effects.pdf?dl=0)

> However, TWFE can be an attractive model for baseline (control)
> outcomes when N & T are modest" but not  exible for large dimensions.
>
> - Guido Imbens (Sargan Lecture, RES 2021).